# Retrieve Jtree from DataBase Table

Tags: java, database, swing, jtree, linkedhashmap

I made an Jtree in which take values from user and store it in linkedHashMap and then LinkedHashMap values store in a database table (with columns `id,name,parent,level`). Now I retrieve the table from database and I also print all the rows.

But I am unable to understand how I can retrieve Jtree from the table data.

```
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
        String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "Hr", "Hr");
        System.out.println("Connection Established");

         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts");
         System.out.println("id  name    job"+ rs);

         while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("node_Id");
            String name = rs.getString("node_Name");
            String job = rs.getString("node_Parent");
            String lvl = rs.getString("node_Level");
            System.out.println(id+"   "+name+"    "+job+" "+lvl );
            System.out.println("lalalala "+ id);
            System.out.println("nasjdnasj"); 
        }}

        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("connection error "+ e);
        }
```

This is the code which retrieve table columns from database and prints all the values

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Note that the code snippets are not runnable code snippets and should be formatted using the `{}` button instead. 3) Please revisit some of your earlier questions and see if there is an answer that can be accepted. 4) Be sure to add relevant tags. E.G. for this, both Swing & Java.